# How would one 'return' a value in Assembly/LC-3?

Tags: assembly, return, lc3

We are supposed to be creating programs in LC3 assembly based on 'pseudo-code' that we are given.

How would I 'return' a value in assembly?

Any and all help is appreciated.

pseudo-code:

```
int brandonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= -16) {
        return -n/3 + 8;
    }
    else {
        int c1 = brandonacci(n - 2);
        int c2 = brandonacci(n - 7);
        return c1 / 2 - 2 * c2 - 3; }
     }
}
```

Comment: this is dangerously close to a homework question, find your actual question and ask that, not "help me with this...".

Comment: I would suggest that you simply ask what appears to be the real question here: "How would one 'return' a value in Assembly/LC-3?" we don't need/want to know what kind of homework you are doing.

Comment: Firstly, that is just one part of the homework and secondly, I only put that up there to show what I mean when I ask about a 'return' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in LC3 assembly you would return a value using a register of your choice.

This means that you would perform a JSR or JSRR to call your subroutine/function, store the value in a register at the end, and RET. Since we know that these instructions only utilize the R7 register we can use the other registers however we wish.